# Python: How to delete rows of data in a text file based on a greater than condition in two different columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove lines from a text file which has data consisting of 23 columns and at least 6000 rows.  I would like to remove all rows with a value greater than 41.54 in column 14 but only when there is also a value greater than 49.97 in column 13.  This way instead of all rows with values greater than 41.54 in column13 being removed, it would only remove the rows that have both conditions.

I'm including what I have started with for only removing rows with values greater than 41.54 in column 14.  The columns do not have names.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('F625W8.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
df = df[df.columns[13] > 41.54]
```

But this gives me this error: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 61 fields in line 15, saw 64

How could I edit this to include the conditions I need?  I am very new to Python and it is the only language I am even vaguely familiar with.  Thank you in advance!  Below is an example of what the data actually looks like.

[image: Example of what the contents of the file looks like]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text is not tidy and you're getting this error as a result. It looks like the data starts at row 23 so:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('F625W8.txt', sep=" ", header=None, skiprows=23)
df = df[df.columns[13] > 41.54]
```

`skiprows` does what it sounds like, skipping all the rows before its argument before reading. *Edit*: you can also use `comment` to skip lines beginning with, for example, `#`

Alternate approaches can be taken using the `error_bad_lines` arg for dropping rows with too many fields, or `warn_bad_lines` to do the same with warnings. `skipfooter` skips rows at the bottom, and `nrows` limits the number of rows to read. Finally, `usecols` can limit which columns to read. By mixing and matching the use of these arguments, you can have fine-grained control over what data is read from the file.

**Edit:** After trying my suggestion you indicated that this let you load the data but you're having trouble with the next line `df = df[df.columns[13] > 41.54]`

The simple answer is that `df.columns` is an array (pandas index) of strings. So you're comparing a string to a number. The following can work but it could just lead you to the next problem.

```
df = df[df[df.columns[13]] > 41.54]
```

For example if any of the values in that column can't be compared to a `float`, you would get the same error.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"d": [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,], "x": [4,5,6,7,8,"nine"]})

df = df[df["x"] > 7] # TypeError: '>' not supported...
df = df[df["d"] > 7] # Runs fine
```

In this instance you would need to cast to something with those string values, probably by using `Series.apply` which you can check out [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Comment: Just noting that `comment` is also useful argument in `read_csv` for these situations. Could use `comment='#'` to get pandas to ignore lines beginning with that character, as it appears that all the preamble in your file has.

Comment: Thank you! That clears some things up.  I've tried some of your suggestions. `warn_bad_lines` seems to take car of that issue, but now I am getting something like: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Comment: @SamanthaMartin I'm glad my answer helped. I made an edit to my answer to help explain the `TypeError` you are seeing.